# C# ajax button click

Tags: c#, ajax, buttonclick

```
<button name="button" class="button" onclick="translateEnglish()">Translate to English</button>
```

I must click this button automaticly on C# web browser I try this code but didn't work:

```
HtmlElementCollection elc = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
foreach (HtmlElement el in elc)
{
   if (el.GetAttribute("onclick").Equals("translateEnglish()"))
   {
       el.InvokeMember("Click");
   }
}
```

Comment: "didn't work" - the most unhelpful phrase you could use. WHAT doesn't work?  WHAT should it do?  WHAT is it doing that it shouldn't?  Are you aware of "server side controls" (i.e. `<asp:Button>`)?

Comment: Soner bey bu siteyi fazla bilmiyorum türkçe konuşmak serbestmi bilmiyorum ama sıkıntımı şöyle söyleyebilirim. Bir c# programı yaptım ve koyduğum butona tıklayınca ajax ile kodlanmış sitedeki butona tıklamasını istiyorum bu konuda fazla bir bilgim yok yardımcı olduğunuz için çok teşekkür ediyorum.

Comment: Sorry @user, this site is for English only

Comment: Sorry @freefaller Im new in this site :(

Comment: What does "C# web browser" means to you?, are you trying to click a button on client side, from the server side??